# How to check if the device time is equal to the time stored in FirebaseDatabase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-calendar

I'm storing the time at which user is posting something and giving him options to choose a time at which that post will get deleted and then storing this time too in FirebaseDatabase.

The problem is that I'm unable to check that whether the time of the device is equal to the stored time in Firebase so that I can delete it from the database.

I'm storing the time at which the content should get deleted in Firebase in this format: `04:30 PM` and getting it using this code:

```
public void showTime(int hour, int min) {
        if (hour == 0) {
            hour += 12;
            format = "AM";
        } else if (hour == 12) {
            format = "PM";
        } else if (hour > 12) {
            hour -= 12;
            format = "PM";
        } else {
            format = "AM";
        }

        chooseDuration.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hour).append(":").append(min)
                .append(" ").append(format));

    }
```

I'm successfully fetching it from database, but the problem is that I'm unable to create a algorithm which checks that if device time and the time retrieved from database is equal, that content should get deleted.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @m0skit0 please be more descriptive, bro.

Comment: Please read documentation, bruh.